# SQLITE: Unable to remove an unnamed primary key

Tags: sqlite

I have a sqlite table that was originally created with:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`column`);
```

I now need to remove that primary key and create a new one.   Creating a new one is easy, but removing the original seems to be the hard part.  If I do

```
.indices  tablename
```

I don't get the primary key.   Some programs show the primary key as

```
Indexes: 1
    [] PRIMARY
```

The index name is typically in the `[]`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does .schema 'tablename'; and .PRAGMA table_info('tablename'); show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

```
PRAGMA INDEX_LIST('MyTable');
```

will give you a list of indices.  This will include the automatically generated index for the primary key which will be called something like `'sqlite_autoindex_MyTable_1'`.

But unfortunately you cannot drop this index...

```
sqlite> drop index sqlite_autoindex_MyTable_1;
SQL error: index associated with UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint cannot be dropped
```

All you can do is re-create the table without the primary key.

Answer (score 2):

I the database glossary; a primary-key is a type of index where the index order is typically results in the physical ordering of the raw database records. That said any database engine that allows the primary key to be changed is likely reordering the database... so most do not and the operation is up to the programmer to create a script to rename the table and create a new one. So if you want to change the PK there is no magic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from sqlite_master;
table|x|x|2|CREATE TABLE x (a text, b text, primary key (`a`))
index|sqlite_autoindex_x_1|x|3|
```

You'll see that the second row returned from my quick hack has the index name in the second column, and the table name in the third. Try seeing if that name is anything useful.

Comment: I do not get the second line at all.  The index|sqlite_auto...  line.

Comment: The second & third lines are rows returned by the query. The structure is `type`, `name`, `tbl_name`, `rootpage`, `sql`. You could do a "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'index' AND tbl_name = 'Your_Name'" to just list the indexes from your problem table.

Further, it may be impossible to delete a primary key in SQLite.

Finally, if you're running an older version of SQLite, it may be that your primary key for that is the same kind that's normally hidden. Can you show me your .schema for that table?

Comment: It seems that its just impossible to delete a primary key.  The primary key has no name.  Other keys that I create after the table is made require a name, and those can be found and deleted at will.